# OpenFlow - How are ICMP messages handled

Tags: icmp, sdn, mininet, openflow, ryu

I am running a Ryu controller and a Mininet instance with 2 hosts and 1 switch like below.

H1---S---H2

Code in Ryu controller

```
from ryu.base import app_manager
from ryu.controller import ofp_event
from ryu.controller.handler import CONFIG_DISPATCHER, MAIN_DISPATCHER
from ryu.controller.handler import set_ev_cls
from ryu.ofproto import ofproto_v1_3
from ryu.lib.packet import packet
from ryu.lib.packet import ethernet
from ryu.lib.packet import ether_types


class SimpleSwitch13(app_manager.RyuApp):

OFP_VERSIONS = [ofproto_v1_3.OFP_VERSION]

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SimpleSwitch13, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.mac_to_port = {}

@set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures, CONFIG_DISPATCHER)
def switch_features_handler(self, ev):
    datapath = ev.msg.datapath
    ofproto = datapath.ofproto
    parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
```

Basically **the switch flow table is empty**. In this case, when I run `h1 ping h2` from my mininet console and record the packet exchanges, this is what I get in wireshark from host h1.

[image]

There is no router in the mininet instance. How am I receiving an ICMP Host Destination Unreachable Message from the same host that initiated the ping?

Answer (score 1):

The app code you posted is **not complete**.

For complete simple_switch_13.py, you can get it from the [osrg github](https://github.com/osrg/ryu/blob/master/ryu/app/simple_switch_13.py).

Take a look, it is like this:

```
class SimpleSwitch13(app_manager.RyuApp):
    OFP_VERSIONS = [ofproto_v1_3.OFP_VERSION]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleSwitch13, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mac_to_port = {}

    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures, CONFIG_DISPATCHER)
    def switch_features_handler(self, ev):
        datapath = ev.msg.datapath
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

        match = parser.OFPMatch()
        actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(ofproto.OFPP_CONTROLLER,
                                          ofproto.OFPCML_NO_BUFFER)]
        self.add_flow(datapath, 0, match, actions)

    def add_flow(self, datapath, priority, match, actions, buffer_id=None):
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

        inst = [parser.OFPInstructionActions(ofproto.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS,
                                             actions)]
        if buffer_id:
            mod = parser.OFPFlowMod(datapath=datapath, buffer_id=buffer_id,
                                    priority=priority, match=match,
                                    instructions=inst)
        else:
            mod = parser.OFPFlowMod(datapath=datapath, priority=priority,
                                    match=match, instructions=inst)
        datapath.send_msg(mod)

    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPacketIn, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def _packet_in_handler(self, ev):
        # If you hit this you might want to increase
        # the "miss_send_length" of your switch
        if ev.msg.msg_len < ev.msg.total_len:
            self.logger.debug("packet truncated: only %s of %s bytes",
                              ev.msg.msg_len, ev.msg.total_len)
        msg = ev.msg
        datapath = msg.datapath
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
        in_port = msg.match['in_port']

        pkt = packet.Packet(msg.data)
        eth = pkt.get_protocols(ethernet.ethernet)[0]

        if eth.ethertype == ether_types.ETH_TYPE_LLDP:
            # ignore lldp packet
            return
        dst = eth.dst
        src = eth.src

        dpid = datapath.id
        self.mac_to_port.setdefault(dpid, {})

        self.logger.info("packet in %s %s %s %s", dpid, src, dst, in_port)

        # learn a mac address to avoid FLOOD next time.
        self.mac_to_port[dpid][src] = in_port

        if dst in self.mac_to_port[dpid]:
            out_port = self.mac_to_port[dpid][dst]
        else:
            out_port = ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD

        actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(out_port)]

        # install a flow to avoid packet_in next time
        if out_port != ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD:
            match = parser.OFPMatch(in_port=in_port, eth_dst=dst)
            # verify if we have a valid buffer_id, if yes avoid to send both
            # flow_mod & packet_out
            if msg.buffer_id != ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER:
                self.add_flow(datapath, 1, match, actions, msg.buffer_id)
                return
            else:
                self.add_flow(datapath, 1, match, actions)
        data = None
        if msg.buffer_id == ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER:
            data = msg.data

        out = parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath=datapath, buffer_id=msg.buffer_id,
                                  in_port=in_port, actions=actions, data=data)
        datapath.send_msg(out)
```

This simple_switch_13.py app only handles layer 2 forwarding, which is your case.

As you can see, after the connection established, the `switch_features_handler` will listen on this event and add a `send all flow to controller` flow on the switch.(`table-miss` flow)

And for the normal states, when the controller receives PACKET_IN, it will check if the dst_MAC is in the `mac_to_port`. If yes, then output to the port, and at the same time insert a flow(whose match field is inport and dst_MAC); else(not in the array), the action is set to be FLOOD by assigning the `outport=FLOOD`.

That's the case in Layer 2 switching.

For ICMP messages handling in layer 3 switching, you need to read the `rest_router.py` code, which is a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You get ICMP Host Destination Unreachable because the ARP request is never answered by h2.

Since h1 gets no ARP reply, ICMP error message comes from its own IP stack.

Comment: is there a timeout value that let's the host confirm that no ARP reply has been received and it should issue an ICMP error